# Is there a way to configure the filename for a Neo4j Desktop database dump file to exclude timestamp?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

I'm a first time user of Neo4j and following a training course to install and learn the basics.

I've installed Neo4j Desktop on a Windows machine and can see that it comes with a demo DB called "Movie DBMS". I'm trying to follow steps to dump the database, by stopping the database, clicking on "..." and then "Dump".

The dump errors with the following error in the log file:

[2022-01-31 12:54:36.022] [error] Selecting JVM - Version:11.0.8+10-LTS, Name:OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Vendor:Azul Systems, Inc.
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 128: C:\Users<me>.Neo4jDesktop\relate-data\projects<my project name>\movie-dbms-neo4j-31-Jan-2022-12:54:31.dump

It would appear that the automatic configuration for the dump file is adding a timestamp with includes colons (hh:mm:ss). How can I configure the file name to either exclude the timestamp or avoid using ":"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had no responses. But I've figured it out myself.

The answer was to use the command line to dump the database manually. At that point I can specify my own "--to=" filename which doesn't include a ":".

Details in this section of the manual: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/offline-backup/#offline-backup